# BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) not able to find another BLE device

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, android-ble

I am trying to scan another BLE device, but it is not finding another BLE device.
Instead, it scanned a Bluetooth device with api <18.

This is my code :

```
package com.example.blescan;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DeviceScanActivity extends ListActivity {
    private LeDeviceListAdapter mLeDeviceListAdapter;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private boolean mScanning;
    private Handler mHandler;

    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    // Stops scanning after 10 seconds.
    private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
        mHandler = new Handler();

        // Use this check to determine whether BLE is supported on the device.
        // Then you can
        // selectively disable BLE-related features.
        if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.ble_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            finish();
        }
        // Initializes a Bluetooth adapter. For API level 18 and above, get a
        // reference to
        // BluetoothAdapter through BluetoothManager.
        final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
        // Checks if Bluetooth is supported on the device.
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_bluetooth_not_supported,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        if (!mScanning) {
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_stop).setVisible(false);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_scan).setVisible(true);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_refresh).setActionView(null);
        } else {
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_stop).setVisible(true);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_scan).setVisible(false);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_refresh).setActionView(
                    R.layout.actionbar_indeterminate_progress);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_scan:
            mLeDeviceListAdapter.clear();
            scanLeDevice(true);
            break;
        case R.id.menu_stop:
            scanLeDevice(false);
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Ensures Bluetooth is enabled on the device. If Bluetooth is not
        // currently enabled,
        // fire an intent to display a dialog asking the user to grant
        // permission to enable it.
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(
                        BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            }
        }
        // Initializes list view adapter.
        mLeDeviceListAdapter = new LeDeviceListAdapter();
        setListAdapter(mLeDeviceListAdapter);
        scanLeDevice(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // User chose not to enable Bluetooth.
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT
                && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            finish();
            return;
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        scanLeDevice(false);
        mLeDeviceListAdapter.clear();
    }

    private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
        if (enable) {
            // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mScanning = false;
                    mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
            }, SCAN_PERIOD);
            mScanning = true;
            mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        } else {
            mScanning = false;
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        }
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    // Adapter for holding devices found through scanning.
    private class LeDeviceListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mLeDevices;
        private LayoutInflater mInflator;

        public LeDeviceListAdapter() {
            super();
            mLeDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
            mInflator = DeviceScanActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
        }

        public void addDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
            if (!mLeDevices.contains(device)) {
                mLeDevices.add(device);
            }
        }

        public BluetoothDevice getDevice(int position) {
            return mLeDevices.get(position);
        }

        public void clear() {
            mLeDevices.clear();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mLeDevices.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return mLeDevices.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder;
            // General ListView optimization code.
            if (view == null) {
                view = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.listitem_device, null);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.deviceAddress = (TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.device_address);
                viewHolder.deviceName = (TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.device_name);
                view.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }

            BluetoothDevice device = mLeDevices.get(i);
            final String deviceName = device.getName();
            if (deviceName != null && deviceName.length() > 0)
                viewHolder.deviceName.setText(deviceName);
            else
                viewHolder.deviceName.setText(R.string.unknown_device);
            viewHolder.deviceAddress.setText(device.getAddress());

            return view;
        }
    }

    // Device scan callback.
    private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi,
                byte[] scanRecord) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device);
                    mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }
    };

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView deviceName;
        TextView deviceAddress;
    }

    // ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED: connected to a GATT server.
    // ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED: disconnected from a GATT server.
    // ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED: discovered GATT services.
    // ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE: received data from the device. This can be 
    // result of read or notification operations.

}
```

These are the requested permissions:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

Please help me.

Comment: Please post your code properly by which other people can understand your code easily.

Comment: what more you needed in it